# To understand the behaviour of script when running over SSH

Tags: server, bash, ssh, rsync

Alright, lately I have been facing an odd behavior. 
I have small bash script which simply takes mysql dump remotely and then store data on the server itself which later get rsynced to backup server.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh -p 82001 user@remotehost  "mysqldump -u db_user -pSomePass mydb" |  gzip -c >  /sql/mybackup.sql.gz
```

But what I am seeing that files are being created on local server under /sql but not on remote server.

Does that means that mysqldump is working over remote server and then data is piped over network to this local machine then compressed and stored in desired file here.. not on remote ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command after the pipe symbol `gzip -c >  /sql/mybackup.sql.gz` is running on your local machine.

You should use

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 82001 user@remotehost  "mysqldump -u db_user -pSomePass mydb |  gzip -c >  /sql/mybackup.sql.gz"
```

---

Example:

```
% ssh user@host "echo remote" | echo local  
local
user@host's password:

% ssh user@host "echo remote | echo local"
user@host's password:
```

Answer (score 4):

Not that odd, you're piping the output of the `ssh` command within your shell; you should pipe it within the shell on the remote server:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh -p 82001 user@remotehost  "mysqldump -u db_user -pSomePass mydb | gzip -c >  /sql/mybackup.sql.gz"
```

Also mind that you're not using `bash`, but `sh`. To use `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh -p 82001 user@remotehost  "mysqldump -u db_user -pSomePass mydb | gzip -c >  /sql/mybackup.sql.gz"
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two commands?

Comment: The shebang, sorry =)